# Android: Notification and Binded Service

Tags: android, binding, notifications

I have MyActivity and MyService (which plays music). I have also notification (in Notifications bar) but when I press it, MyActivity opens up in default state (play button is not pressed for e.g., although the music is still playing). This worked OK before I started to work with binding - I am concerned it has to do something with it.

What could be wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

This is my Noification inside my service:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoundRelaxerActivity.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.tickerText = "Soundrelaxer: "+trackTitle;
notification.icon = R.drawable.play;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "SoundRelaxer","Playing: " + trackTitle, pi);
startForeground(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this flag to the `Intent` you're using in your Notification:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

That way a new instance of your Activity will not be created if it exists.

Comment: Actually I'm using PendingIntent (worked upon Developers Guide Tutorial) which doesn't have this type of flag. Or do you mean the Intent with which I start the service? Also, look at the first post update.

Comment: Not the `PendingIntent`, the `Intent` you pass to the `PendingIntent`.